# A mythical question about the fine-structure constant inverse approximation, $137$, and the telephone number for information, $411$.

Tags: terminology, arithmetic, divisibility

For which positive integers $a$, and $b$, does $a^2 + b^2$ divide the concatenation of $a$ and $b$ that is $ab$?

Eg, $4^2 + 11^2 = 137$, which divides $411 = 3  X  137$.

Is a there a mathematical name for the condition on integers $a$, $b$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format numbers and math expressions.

Comment: You can use `\to` for arrows like so $A \to B$

Comment: in which order is the concatenation if c is odd only one of the orderings can work.

Comment: There is an alternate way to write the above example.  
Eg, $411 = (3/10)(1^2 + 37^2)$ $\to$ $137 = (1/3)411$ $\to$ $411$.

Comment: more like a failure of an epic kind.

Comment: There must be a name for these numbers where c is the concatenation.

Comment: You haven't even even specified what order the concatenation is in. it matters as stated. c is the sum not the concatenation

Comment: Resolve "the concatenation of a and b" to mean a before b as read from left to right.  Regardless, with the same range of integer values for each of a, and b, either resolution will do.  For c odd, then one of a, or b must be even; for c odd to divide the concatenation of a and b, with a before b, then at least b must be odd.

Comment: Alf van der Poorten wrote a paper about things like $12^2+33^2=1233$. The title was The Hermite-Serret algorithm and $12^2+33^2$.

Comment: Possibly related is Breu and van der Poorten, Self-similar values of quadratic forms: a remark on pattern and duality, J. Recreat. Math. 35, 202—212 (2010).

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A275986 Positive integers of the form $x*10^k + y$ which also equal $x^2 + y^2$ ($x$, $y$ and $k$ being positive integers), and A. van der Poorten, K. Thomsen, and M. Wiebe, A curious cubic identity and self-similar sums of squares, The Mathematical Intelligencer, v.29(2), pp. 69-73, June 2007, and https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/charlton/writings/squaresumcat/

Comment: @GerryMyerson and everyone else here, thank you for your input.  I am running a computer simulation of this problem in general. If the question is taken off hold, I will, at some point, try to answer my own question with this data, and any other observations. Perhaps, numbers, too, are like personal relationships, in which it's the interrelationships, instead of the actors, themselves, that matter the most.

Comment: To get the question taken off hold, Rem, you had best edit it in accord with the concerns raised in the comments and in the hold notice. Otherwise, it stands a good chance of being deleted.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. How about $3^3 + 7^3 + 1^3 = 371$, $33^3 + 67^3 + 01^3 = 336701$, and on to $333^3 + 667^3 + 001^3 = 333667001$?  Also this one seems to pads itself with $3$'s, $0$'s and $6$'s, but another way around from those of the pattern of $1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153$.  I hope this works out because, in my little theory of everything, and numbers, $153$ and $173$ overlap in the periodic table of the elements.  ($137$ corresponds across to $197$, and, similarly, $125$ to $225$, and so on.) Incidentally, https://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php?short=333667001 .

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: The number 173 has to be directly analogous to the number 153.  The formation of this analogy can't contain also the number 371.  The point is to try to develop a theory of everything from first principles per se.  For me, it has been a drawn-out or iterative process of trying to define what is a physical and mathematical point by working back and forth from rough estimates and ideas of it to and from the higher dimensions to converge on a single "dimensional equation", I call it.  I think that with the thus right "definition" of a point, everything else follows.

Comment: I think that the further properties of numbers are are bound up in the interrelations of simple integers, but not in formal mathematics or other thinking.  There is a lot of information in the simple integers, say, in their permutations, eg, 114, 141, and 411, with respect to the dimensions of physics, and chemistry, etc.  This concatenation question, the ways to find these numerical interrelationships running intertwined beneath the different ways to thus work, reconcile or further "average out" these numbers.

Comment: Seems to me you are trying to build a large structure on the weak foundation of decimal notation. If we worked in, say, base 7, we'd have a whole different set of relations among numbers. I don't think Nature has any preference for one base over another.

Comment: Well, it wasn't until my second or third serious attempt at calibrating the thing with the periodic table of elements, a couple of years ago, that I focused more on the numbers involved.  I just assumed that each number and its base, equation, etc, played its own unique role in things overall.  Some numbers and things are more prevalent than others, but, this is what makes one thing different from another.    I am as sure that an overall solution of things in one way will hold for the others, albeit, in different manners for the others.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of funny numbers going around in funny places, so, I always make a point of saying that those numbers don't really interest me; at least not beyond how we "naturally" come to view and write such numbers, say, 666, 911, and the lucky and unlucky numbers.  We inhabit a universe in which left and right -handedness are distinguishable from afar by the physical difference in magnetic poles, so, what we as naturally take to be the nature of reality may be a collective delusion or other type of bias (of what is appropriate behavior).

Comment: Moreover, how could atoms without an underlying "idea" of where they are headed lead to life?  Sentient life, if it truly is, can't spring from nothingness, especially, were nothingness so balanced, or unbiased, that, say, all number bases were to be applied uniformly everywhere.  Can some dimensions, or applications naturally involve particular numerical bases more than others?  A physical point can be whatever you want it to be, whereas, a mathematical point is always, or supposed to be, well-defined.  Enter how, and to which extent, mind and matter merge. Is math invented, or discovered?

Comment: Perhaps, math, itself, along with every number base is, abstractly, another type of dimension that expands and contracts along with the others, as a safeguard against information loss, so, there is a dimension without any numbers at all. What could the intermediate dimensions entail? We take real numbers to make up all the dimensions, but each must be fundamentally different. The notion that nature has no preference here is only one more to "balance" along with all the others. A universe can't know ahead of time what it is to be, but this form of "balance" isn't the same as a simple balance.

Comment: For what it's worth, I now have a fairly straightforward way to show how the numerals work out in all possible ways in base 10, which, if allow for a couple of the digits to physically invert, becomes its own frame of reference for the numerals.  But, I would never post it here because of the prevailing attitude against anything truly new and experimental.

Comment: Finally, a value for the electromagnetic fine-structure constant to an arbitrary number of digits with a billion-to-one (against) chance of being wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write $a\|b$ for the concatenation of $a$ and $b$, e.g., $142\|857=142857$. Then the special case $a\|b=a^2+b^2$ is tabulated [here](http://oeis.org/A275986). The first few terms are

$101, 1233, 8833, 10001, 10100, 990100, 1000001, 5882353, 94122353, 99009901, 100000001$, $100010000, 1765038125, 2584043776, 7416043776, 8235038125, 9901009901, 10000000001$, $48600220401, 116788321168, 123288328768, 601300773101, 876712328768, 883212321168$, $990100990100, 999900010000, 1000000000001, 1000001000000$.

The accompanying text begins,

The condition $x^2 + y^2 = 10^kx + y$ is equivalent to $(2x-10^k)^2 + (2y-1)^2 = 10^{2k} + 1$, so to find these sequence elements it is necessary to write $10^{2k} + 1$ as the sum of two squares.

There is a link to A. van der Poorten, K. Thomsen, and M. Wiebe, A curious cubic identity and self-similar sums of squares, The Mathematical Intelligencer, v.29(2), pp. 69-73, June 2007.

EDIT: Now, let's look at the general case, $a\|b=(a^2+b^2)r$. We write this as $$10^ka+b=(a^2+b^2)r$$ and after a little algebra we get $$(2ar-10^k)^2+(2br-1)^2=10^{2k}+1$$ so again it's a question of writing $10^{2k}+1$ as a sum of two squares. Let's do a couple of examples.

$\mathbf{k=2}$, $(2ar-100)^2+(2br-1)^2=10001=100^2+1^2=76^2+65^2$. Taking first $100^2+1^2$, we get $$2br-1=1,\quad2ar-100=100$$ so $br=1$, $ar=100$. The only solution is $r=1$, $b=1$, $a=100$, and $100\|01=100^2+01^2$.

Now using $76^2+65^2$, we get $$2br-1=65,\quad2ar-100=\pm76$$ from which we get $$br=33,\quad ar=88{\rm\ or\ }12$$ We get solutions

$r=1$, $b=33$, $a=88$: $88\|33=88^2+33^2$
$r=1$, $b=33$, $a=12$: $12\|33=12^2+33^2$
$r=3$, $b=11$, $a=4$: $4\|11=3(4^2+11^2)$ (which started this whole question)
$r=11$, $b=3$, $a=8$: $803=11(8^2+03^2)$.

Let's do $\mathbf{k=4}$. We get $10^8+1=10000^2+1^2=8824^2+4705^2$.

$2br-1=1$, $2ar-10000=10000$ leads to $r=1$, $b=1$, $a=10000$ and the trivial $10000\|0001=10000^2+0001^2$.

$2br-1=4705$, $2ar-10000=\pm8824$ leads to
$br=2353=13\times181$, $ar=9412=4\times13\times181$, or $ar=588=3\times4\times49$.

We get $r=1$, $b=2353$, $a=9412$: $9412\|2353=9412^2+2353^2$
$r=1$, $b=2353$, $a=588$: $588\|2353=588^2+2353^2$
$r=13$, $b=181$, $a=724$: $7240181=13(724^2+181^2)$
$r=181$, $b=13$, $a=52$: $520013=181(52^2+13^2)$
$r=2353$, $b=1$, $a=4$: $40001=2353(4^2+1^2)$.

Comment: The above mentioned article may be found at https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michael_Kleber/publication/225591088_A_curious_cubic_identity_and_self-similar_sums_of_squares/links/55c635f308aeca747d633576/A-curious-cubic-identity-and-self-similar-sums-of-squares.pdf .  More solutions from the special case c is also the concatenation may be found at https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/charlton/writings/squaresumcat/solutions.1-46.txt .

Comment: A simulation of values for a, and b up to 60,000 without considering leading zeros yields the additional results: $646010944 = 4(6460^2 + 10944^2)$; $1854010944 = 4(18540^2 + 10944^2)$; $1292021888 = 2(12920^2 + 21888^2)$; $2472014592 = 3(24720^2 + 14592^2)$; $1765038125 = 17650^2 + 38125^2$; $2584043776 = 25840^2 + 43776^2$; and $3708021888 = 2(37080^2 + 21888^2)$.  Perhaps, it's more striking that a number can be made to appear to be larger than itself.  Numbers made to appear to remain themselves are, perhaps, a sort of controlled trial for the others.  Can other types of numbers result?

Comment: A little algebra?  $10^ka+b = (a^2+b^2)r$ $\to$ $(10^ka+b)r = (a^2+b^2)r^2$ $\to$ $(a^2r^2-10^kar)+(b^2r^2-br)=0$ $\to$ $(4a^2r^2-4*10^kar)+(4b^2r^2-4br)=0$ $\to$ $(4a^2r^2-4*10^kar+10^{2k})+(4b^2r^2-4br+1)=10^{2k}+1$ $\to$ $(2ar-10^k)^2+(2br-1)^2=10^{2k}+1$.